# Dealing with noisy training labels in text classification using deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, supervised-learning, keras

I have a dataset that comprises of sentences and corresponding multi-labels (e.g. a sentence can belong to multiple labels). Using a combination of Convolutional Neural Networks and Recurrent Neural Nets on language models (Word2Vec) I'm able to achieve a good accuracy. However, it's /too/ good at modelling the output, in the sense that a lot of labels are arguably wrong and thus the output too. This means that the evaluation (even with regularization and dropout) gives a wrong impression, since I have no ground truth. Cleaning up the labels would be prohibitively expensive. So I'm left to explore "denoising" the labels somehow. I've looked at things like ["Learning from Massive Noisy Labeled Data for Image Classification"](http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~xgwang/papers/xiaoXYHWcvpr15.pdf), however they assume to learn some sort of noise covariace matrix on the outputs, which I'm not sure how to do in Keras.

Has anyone dealt with the problem of noisy labels in a mutli-label text classification setting before (ideally using Keras or similar) and has good ideas on how to learn a robust model with noisy labels?